# Need help deserializing JSON object in asp.net inside [WebMethod]

Tags: .net, ajax, json, deserialization, webmethod

I am using C# and my project is .NET 3.5 website project. Trying to deserialize Json object that looks like this:

```
{
"jsonData": [
    {
        "name": "sEcho",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "iColumns",
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "sColumns",
        "value": ","
    },
    {
        "name": "iDisplayStart",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "iDisplayLength",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "mDataProp_0",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "sSearch_0",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "bRegex_0",
        "value": false
    },
    {
        "name": "bSearchable_0",
        "value": true
    },
    {
        "name": "bSortable_0",
        "value": true
    },
    {
        "name": "mDataProp_1",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "sSearch_1",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "bRegex_1",
        "value": false
    },
    {
        "name": "bSearchable_1",
        "value": true
    },
    {
        "name": "bSortable_1",
        "value": true
    },
    {
        "name": "sSearch",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "bRegex",
        "value": false
    },
    {
        "name": "iSortCol_0",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "sSortDir_0",
        "value": "asc"
    },
    {
        "name": "iSortingCols",
        "value": 1
    }
]
}
```

I have also installed in my project http://james.newtonking.com/json

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string PostAjaxMethod(List<object> jsonData)
    {
    // Code here to deserialize the object
    }
```

I can't figure out how to do that. I know that there must be another class to which I will deserialize the object but need help on the structure of the class.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!!!

UPDATE:

I need code that would look similar to this 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ...
However I have "jsonData" in my json object and I don't really need it. This is used to pass data between ajax call and WebMethod

```
"data": JSON.stringify({ jsonData : aoData })
```

so is there an extra step to remove it before deserializing the object?

UPDATE:

Changed

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string PostAjaxMethod(List<object> jsonData)
```

to this

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string PostAjaxMethod(List<MyTestClass> jsonData)
```

added a class

```
    public class MyTestClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

almost what I want except I need it to be in this format

```
sEcho would be set to 1
iColumns would be set to 2 etc
```

Comment: Your problem is that your `json` do not represent a list of object. I suggest you to remove the root `jsondata`. And start doing things right, create a C# class that represent your `json` object...

Comment: @gustavodidomenico to pass Json object to [WebMethod] in aps.net I have to name it! That is why jsonData is there. In my [WebMethod] i get public static string PostAjaxMethod(List<object> jsonData) <- see this. When I look inside jsonData everything I need is there and 100% CORRECT! I need to desirialize it, just don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

In that case, the param for the WebMethod jsonData, must be a string.

Then, you create a JArray object and initialize it as the result of parsing the string. And then you can access the properties as a multi dimensional dictionary array. Note that in order to parse the string correctly it must be an array. In javascript you can create the array in this way:

```
var jsonObject = {
      "name" : "Foo"
};
var arr = [];
arr.push(jsonObject);

//Now send the object to the server
//Notice that you must use JSON.stringify() in order to send the data to the server
```

Asp.net code:

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string PostAjaxMethod(string jsonData)
{
    JArray _jsonData = JArray.Parse(jsonData);
    string name = _jsonData[0]["name"].toString();
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but i need something similar to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Comment: Sorry but this is not true...You don't need to manual deserialize the json.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico do you have an example of code or link to how to do that?

Comment: Certainly...http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/